# Firefox add-on to find unclosed HTML elements

Tags: html, validation, firefox, plugins, firefox-addon

Are there any add-ons (plug-ins) for Firefox to find unclosed HTML elements?

**Example:**

```
<div>
    <label>
    </label>

    <div> <!-- Previous 'div' tag is not closed! -->
</div>
```

Comment: A validator will tell you the HTML is broken (without necessarily pointing out the right spot, though)

Comment: **Related:** [Firefox addon or other tool to locally validate HTML pages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/918419/1497596)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably mean to validate HTML code, [Html Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/html-validator/) could be used for that.

Comment: it crash my firefox! ahha nice :)

Comment: @markzzz: I would suggest sending the developers the link to your crash report (http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Firefox%20crashes#w_getting-help-with-your-crash). Judging by the absence of negative reviews, I guess that such crashes are uncommon.